# Upload File in node js wd automation testing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am writing test scripts in `node js - wd` testing framework to upload a file in a web application. The HTML code does not consist of input tag as there is a button located there and when clicking on that button the Linux modal popup comes. So, not able to do this with sendkeys. Because sendkeys work with `<input>` tag.

And because I am running this on Linux machine , autoit tool is not working there.

HTML code for this:

```
<button ngf-select="" class="btn btn-sm bgm-gray ng-pristine ng-valid 
waves-effect ng-touched" ng-model="datasetFile" 
ngf-change="fileSelected($files, $event)" ng-multiple="false" 
accept="*.csv" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="10MB" resetonclick="false">

   <i class="zmdi zmdi-cloud-upload p-r-5"></i>
   <span class="text-capitalize">Upload CSV or Zip</span>

</button>
```

Comment: There is currently no way to automate file uploading as a user would do it. At previous companies, we provided a special endpoint that would run the upload as an API call.